# Row sums doesn't match when using case_when and rowSums in R

Tags: r, dplyr, recode, mutate

I made up this example df to make an example.

```
set.seed(357)
# Generate binary variables
var1 <- sample(c(0, 1, NA), 200, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.2))
var2 <- sample(c(0, 1, NA), 200, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1))
var3 <- sample(c(0, 1, NA), 200, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.35, 0.25))

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
# Show the first few rows of the data frame
head(df)
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    0    0
2    0    0    0
3    1    1    0
4   NA    0    1
5   NA    1    0
6    0   NA   NA
```

As you can see, my example df have 200 binary responses (o, 1) and some random missing values which aren't in the same rows or represent the same proportion of missings in any column.

I'm triying to recode all my vars into one, I would like it to be 1 if any of the vars is 1, and zero if all vars are zero.

```
library(tidyverse)
df<- df %>% mutate(
    x1= case_when( var1== 0 &  var2== 0 & var3== 0  ~ 0,
                       var1 == 1 | var2 == 1 | var3 == 1 ~ 1
    )
  )

table(df$x1)
#Output
  0   1 
 11 167
```

That seems ok, but then I wanted to do some calculations with my vars, let's say a sum of all the binary vars in one, so I used `rowSums`

```
df<- df %>%mutate(
  x2 = rowSums(cbind(var1, var2, var3), na.rm = F))

table(df$x2)
#Output
 0  1  2  3 
11 38 51 13
```

I used the `na.rm = F` so the sum doesn't ignore the NA. I know the max possible value is 3 and the min possible value is zero; I wanted to categorize the values of x2 like 0 = "None"; 1 = "low"; 2 = "medium"; 3 = "high". All that would be easy but I stopped because I noticed something odd.

As you can see, the zero values are the same in both x1 and x2, that's what I expected, but the count of "1", "2" and "3" values in x2 doesn't match the count of "1" in x1

```
38+51+13
[1] 102
```

I don't understand why those counts doesn't match. I tried `na.rm = TRUE` but then not even the zero values count match. I suppose something is happening with the position of NAs in var1, var2 and var3, but now I'm not sure which one is really the calculation I'm looking for.

Hope you can help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, it doesn't match because you have NA's in `x1` and you handle them in `x2`. For example, see rows 5 or 7 in the example below where x1 is NA and x2 is 0 as you ignore NA in "var" columns.

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(357)
var1 <- sample(c(0, 1, NA), 200, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.2))
var2 <- sample(c(0, 1, NA), 200, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1))
var3 <- sample(c(0, 1, NA), 200, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.35, 0.25))

xy <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

xy <- xy %>% mutate(
  x1 = case_when(
    var1 == 0 &  var2 == 0 & var3 == 0  ~ 0,
    var1 == 1 | var2 == 1 | var3 == 1 ~ 1
  )
)
xy$x2 <- rowSums(xy, na.rm = TRUE)

> xy
    var1 var2 var3 x2 x1
1      1   NA    1  2  1
2      1    0    0  1  1
3      1    1    1  3  1
4      1    0    1  2  1
5      0    0   NA  0 NA
6      0    1    0  1  1
7     NA    0   NA  0 NA
8      0    0    0  0  0
9      0    1    0  1  1
10    NA    0   NA  0 NA
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is quite obvious. Your "binary" variables are not binary, they are categorical with 0, 1 and NA as possible observations.

When creating `x1`, you assign 0 if **ALL** variables are `0`, but `1` if **ANY** variable is `1`. Hence you only get a `0` if all are `0` and none is `NA`, but a `1` if any is `1` regardless of the others being `0` or `NA`.

On the other hand with `rowSums()` you will get an `NA` if any value is `NA` with `na.rm=F`, but `x1` could be `1` since you only require any value to be `1`. So naturally the counts won't match. With `na.rm=T` on the other hand, you differ with respect to the `0` values. In case of 2 `0`s and one `NA` in a row, `x1` is `NA`, but `x2` would be `0`.

Comment: Thank you, seems `x1` is doing what I'm looking for then.